# Why does this not work? javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this in Javascript:

```
var inx=[2,3,4,5];
var valarray=[];
for (i=0; i<inx.length; i++) {
    valarray[i]==inx[i];
}
for (i=0; i<inx.length; i++) {
    var posi=inx.indexOf(3);
    var valy=valarray[posi-1]+1;
    valarray[i]=valy;
}
alert(valarray);
```

valarray keeps returning nan,nan,nan,nan instead of numbers...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `valarray[i]==inx[i];` doesn’t do what you seem to expect it to.

In JS, `=` is the assignment operator, `==` the equality operator with type coercion, and `===` the strict equality operator.

A few examples:

```
var a;
alert(a = 2);       // 2

alert('2' == '2');  // true
alert(2 == 2);      // true
alert('2' == 2);    // true (because of type coercion, 2 == '2')

alert('2' === '2'); // true
alert(2 === 2.0);   // true
alert('2' === 2);   // false (strict equality: 2 !== '2')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 valarray[i]==inx[i];
```

That's a logical comparison, not an assignment.

```
 valarray[i]=inx[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing where you should be assigning, try this:

```
var inx=[2,3,4,5];
var valarray=[];
for (i=0; i<inx.length; i++) {
valarray[i]=inx[i]; //previously there was a == here
} 
for (i=0; i<inx.length; i++) {
var posi=inx.indexOf(3);
var valy=valarray[posi-1]+1;
valarray[i]=valy;
}
alert(valarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (i=0; i<inx.length; i++) {
    valarray[i]==inx[i];
}
```

you are using a comparison operator `(==)`, and not an assignment `(=)` operator here

Answer (score 0):

it is a javascript error only

you used :

```
valarray[i]==inx[i];
```

you should use :

```
valarray[i]=inx[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    valarray[i]==inx[i];
```

must become

```
    valarray[i]=inx[i];
```